# Can't link OpenCL on Windows with GHC

Tags: windows, haskell, linker, opencl

I'm trying to get the OpenCLRaw bindings to a point where I can use them on windows.  I've forked the the OpenCLRaw repo on github so I can make modifications as needed.  My branch is here:
https://github.com/dagit/OpenCLRaw

I've been mostly working out of my "FunPtr" branch.

The issue I'm having is this:  I installed AMD's OpenCL SDK, converted their Visual Studio specific .lib file to a file that gcc can handle (.a file), but ghc can't seem to link with it.  I get undefined symbols for everything I use in the OpenCL API.

I was able to build a "trivial" C program and link it using the .a file that I generated and gcc from mingw (not from the Haskell install).  I'm using the latest windows release of the Haskell platform.

These are the steps I used for generating the .a file:
http://forums.amd.com/forum/messageview.cfm?catid=390&threadid=138890

I used the commands in the example script (e.g., gendef and dlltool).  I've tried to use 32bit everything as much as possible, as I know that GHC will want everything to be 32bit, so I don't think it's a 32bit vs. 64bit issue.

Does anyone know if there is something different about invoking gcc under ghc instead of the gcc that I get from mingw?

I've also played with the ghc command line (I used cabal-dev --verbose=3 to inspect the command line) and I'm still unable to massage it into a working state.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If I use pexports instead of gendef then it strips out all the @s after function names.  This allows GHC to use the library file for linking but now a) gcc fails to link with that file and b) my trivial program segfaults when it calls clGetPlatfromIDs.

Comment: I dont test it on Windows, but I notice that OpenCLRaw has several bugs with type, I madfe myself a opencl bind that works for me, https://github.com/zhensydow/opencl

Comment: @Zhen, do you have any plans to put your binding on Hackage?  The first place I look for haskell stuff is hackage, followed by google searches.  Your library looks like an improvements over Jeff's.  It's a shame it doesn't show up on hackage and google.

Comment: I plan to put in hackage, but i want to test it a little more

Comment: I just added it to hackage, http://hackage.haskell.org/package/OpenCL, it isn't stable enough but maybe I can get feedback to enhance it.

Comment: Thanks!  I took a look and, at least on windows, we'll need to convert it to use stdcall.  I'll start using your bindings over OpenCLRaw and submit patches for things that I think need to be fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenCL uses the [stdcall](http://www.khronos.org/message_boards/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=2562) convention, but `OpenCLRaw` is using `ccall`.  This creates several issues.  The main one being that the linker wants the function name symbols to end in @NN where NN depends on the function.

As it turns out, the correct way to generate libOpenCL.a is as follows (from a mingw shell):

```
cp /c/Windows/System32/OpenCL.dll .
gendef OpenCL.dll
dlltool -l libOpenCL.a -d OpenCL.def -k -A
```

This will generate libOpenCL.a that ghc can correctly use for linking, but only if OpenCLRaw is modified to use stdcall instead of ccall.

Now that I understand the problem I can fix the `OpenCLRaw` bindings to do the right thing on Windows.

When I used pexports instead of gendef, I was able to remove the @NN from the symbol names, but then the resulting program started to segfault.  This is because the symbol was found but the calling convention was incorrect, probably leading to corrupted stacks.

The main lesson for me is that your FFI binding must match your C library's calling convention.